# My android aplication crashes a second time I load a dialog

Tags: java, android, xml, android-fragments

I have an adroid aplication that shows a `Dialog` that displays some data when you tap the respective item in the `listview` and works fine, but the second time I tap on another item, it crashes.

The list view calls an xml and inside I call a map fragment, that map fragment makes it crash, for some reason.

This is the `itemlistdialog`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <fragment
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="285dp"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
        android:id="@+id/map" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Here I call open the dialog everytime there is a tap in the list.

```
lista.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
@Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        LayoutInflater factory = LayoutInflater.from(this);
        View listDialogView = factory.inflate(R.layout.itemlistdialog, null);

        Dialog d = new AlertDialog.Builder(aux,AlertDialog.THEME_HOLO_LIGHT)
        //HERE I ADD THE DATA THAT WILL BE DISPLAYED IN THE DIALOG
}
```

Edit: 
This is the full error.
Error is too large to add here
http://prntscr.com/6gyng6

Comment: Post (add to the question) your Logcat.

Comment: I'm sorry I don't understand.

Comment: http://www.herongyang.com/Android/Debug-adb-logcat-Java-Exception-in-AndroidRuntime-Error-Log.html

Comment: we are asking you to post the error from your logcat window appears on app crash

Comment: For some reason my computer cant run any emulator, so I use a device to test the app.

Comment: @Mavi Even a device will produce the logcat error

Comment: I hope this is what you asked for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to dismiss the dialog every time.
For example:

You can try both, either

```
dialog.cancel();
```

or

```
dialog.dismiss();
```

in the both implementation of setPositiveButton and setNegativeButton.

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder1 = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
            builder1.setMessage("Write your message here.");
            builder1.setCancelable(true);
            builder1.setPositiveButton("Yes",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    dialog.cancel();
                }
            });
            builder1.setNegativeButton("No",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    dialog.cancel();
                }
            });

            AlertDialog alert11 = builder1.create();
            alert11.show();
```

Answer (score 1):

Use MapView instead of MapFragment. MapFragment has some detatching problem, so when you open the dialog second time, it crashes because first MapFragment is still not detached.